# Updating annotation coordinates/location in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, xcode6.3, mkpointannotation

I queried a set of coordinates for users around me from Parse(PFGeoPoint) and I have created annotations for said locations/coordinates. I will be updating the users location every 5 seconds and updating the location of the annotations, everything is working fine except for the fact that I'm having to remove and add annotations instead of them moving on their own similar to lyft, is there a way to do this in swift? please reply, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. As I can see from your tags, you are using `MKPointAnnotation` , so you an access its `coordinate` property and update it as you wish.

```
var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
```

So all you have to do is set it up like this:

```
annotation.coordinate = newCoordinate
```

For more information, please look at [Accessing the Annotation’s Location](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPointAnnotation_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKPointAnnotation/coordinate).

Comment: can you please show some code so i can better understand your answer? thank you!